# How to add a labels as markings in a custom view with CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I have a custom UIView class which I use to draw an arc. What I want to achieve is to add labels around this arc as gauge reading. Here is the output I am trying to achieve

[image]

I am able to draw the arc but I am not sure how can I add labels to it. This is the code I am using to create the arc.

Custom UIView class

```
open class Gauge: UIView {
  var gaugeLayer: CALayer!
  var ringLayer: CAShapeLayer!

  private let uLabel = UILabel()

  func updateLayerProperties() {
      backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
      
      if (ringLayer != nil) {
          ringLayer.strokeEnd = 0.75
      }
  }

  required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      updateLayerProperties()
      addLabel()
  }

  public override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      updateLayerProperties()
      addLabel()
  }

  open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      super.draw(rect)
      updateLayerProperties()
  }

  func resetLayers() {
      layer.sublayers = nil
      ringLayer = nil
  }

  open override func layoutSubviews() {
      resetLayers()
      gaugeLayer = getCircleGauge(rotateAngle)
      layer.addSublayer(gaugeLayer)
      updateLayerProperties()
  }

  func addLabel() {
      uLabel.font = //font
      uLabel.textColor = //color
      addSubview(uLabel)
  }
}
```

Code for arc

```
func getCircleGauge() -> CAShapeLayer {
  let gaugeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  if ringLayer == nil {
      ringLayer = CAShapeLayer.getOval(lineWidth, strokeStart: 0, strokeEnd: 0.75, strokeColor: UIColor.clear, fillColor: UIColor.clear, shadowRadius: shadowRadius, shadowOpacity: shadowOpacity, shadowOffsset: CGSize.zero, bounds: bounds)
      ringLayer.frame = layer.bounds
      gaugeLayer.addSublayer(ringLayer)
  }
  gaugeLayer.frame = layer.bounds
  gaugeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
  gaugeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(gaugeLayer.transform, CGFloat(rotateAngle * 2 - pi_2 * 5 / 2), 0, 0, 1)
  ringLayer.lineCap = .round
  return gaugeLayer
}
```

When I tried adding UILabel in the custom view in its init the app crashed

```
view.superview is nil during traversal after it has appeared in superview subviews
```

I am not sure what is the issue? Do I add UILabels or is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Do you simply need **labels**? We need to see the code you used to try adding `UILabel` to know why it crashed.

Comment: The labels are the readings on the arc

Comment: Basically I want to show reading from 0 to max at some interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to do this... you could add `UILabel`s, or you could use `CATextLayer`... depending on what else you might want to do with this could affect how you want to go about it.

First, your code is doing a few things it shouldn't do, so let's start with cleaning that up a bit.

Instead of using an oval with `.strokeEnd: 0.75`, let's use an arc that is 75% of a full circle (which is 270º), with the "gap" at the bottom. 0º (zero) is at "3 o'clock", so we define a clockwise arc from 135º (90º + 45º) to 405º (135º + 270º):

[image]

This will also come in handy later when positioning the labels.

Most people find it easier to think in terms of **degrees** rather than `.pi`, and "circle math" uses **radians**, we'll use this common extension to convert between them:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { self * 180 / .pi }
}
```

So our starting point is to write a "basic" `UIView` subclass:

```
class BasicGuage: UIView {

    private let guageLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        guageLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        guageLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        guageLayer.lineCap = .round
        guageLayer.lineWidth = 16.0

        layer.addSublayer(guageLayer)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // radius is 1/2 of the width
        let radius: CGFloat = bounds.width * 0.5
        
        // center point
        let cntr: CGPoint = .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        
        // clockwise arc leaving a 25% (90º) "gap" at the bottom
        //  start at 135º (90.0º + 45.0º)
        let startAngle: Double = 135.0
        //  end at 3/4 of a full circle
        let endAngle: Double = startAngle + 270.0
        
        bez.addArc(withCenter: cntr, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle.degreesToRadians, endAngle: endAngle.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
        
        // set the guage path
        guageLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    }
    
}
```

and a simple controller to show it:

```
class BasicGuageTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let guage = BasicGuage()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(guage)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            guage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            guage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guage.widthAnchor),
            guage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            guage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])

        guage.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
}
```

That gives us this output:

[image]

You'll notice the arc extends outside the bounds of the view... and, we'll be adding labels around the outside, so we'll need to make the radius smaller than one-half of the view width. But we'll get to that shortly.

The next step is to add labels. We'll start with just one.

Very little difference from `BasicGuage` class:

```
class BasicGuageWithLabel: UIView {
    
    private let guageLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    private let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        guageLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        guageLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        guageLayer.lineCap = .round
        guageLayer.lineWidth = 16.0
        
        layer.addSublayer(guageLayer)
        
        // add the label
        label.text = "Test"
        addSubview(label)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // radius is 1/2 of the width
        let radius: CGFloat = bounds.width * 0.5
        
        // center point
        let cntr: CGPoint = .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        
        // clockwise arc leaving a 25% (90º) "gap" at the bottom
        //  start at 135º (90.0º + 45.0º)
        let startAngle: Double = 135.0
        //  end at 3/4 of a full circle
        let endAngle: Double = startAngle + 270.0
        
        bez.addArc(withCenter: cntr, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle.degreesToRadians, endAngle: endAngle.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
        
        // set the guage path
        guageLayer.path = bez.cgPath
        
        // position the label
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.center = cntr
    }
    
}
```

We've added a `UILabel` and centered it in the view, so (using that same view controller class), it now looks like this:

[image]

We will, of course, need more than one label, so we'll eventually use an array of `[UILabel]`.

To position the labels around the outside of the arc, we can define (but not draw) a circle with a **larger radius**, and then use a common extension for finding the point on the circle:

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func pointOnCircle(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let x = center.x + radius * cos(angle)
        let y = center.y + radius * sin(angle)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
```

The process will be:

- add a label with the specified 0-100 value
- calculate the degree increment based on that value's *percentage* of the total "range"
- find the point on the "label circle" using that degree
- center the label at that point

Here's the idea:

[image]

We're adding two values - 20 and 30. The degree-range is 270º.

20 is 20% of 100, so we use the starting angle of 135 plus 20% of 270 (54):

```
135 + 54 == 189
```

30 is 30% of 100, so we use the starting angle of 135 plus 30% of 270 (81):

```
135 + 81 == 216
```

so the "20" label goes on the dashed-circle radius at `189º` and the "30" label goes at `216º`.

Here's an example `Gauge` view class that has the sizing and label placement:

```
// get the point on a circle at specific radian
extension CGPoint {
    static func pointOnCircle(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, angle: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let x = center.x + radius * cos(angle)
        let y = center.y + radius * sin(angle)
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}

extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { self * 180 / .pi }
}

class Guage: UIView {
    
    // when the values are set, we need to
    //  - create any new labels needed
    //  - update the text and size of the labels
    //  - hide any extra labels
    public var values: [Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            for i in 0..<values.count {
                if i <= theLabels.count {
                    let v = UILabel()
                    v.font = labelFont
                    v.textColor = .red
                    addSubview(v)
                    theLabels.append(v)
                }
                theLabels[i].text = "\(values[i])"
                theLabels[i].sizeToFit()
                theLabels[i].isHidden = false
            }
            for i in values.count..<theLabels.count {
                theLabels[i].isHidden = true
            }
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    // you may end up making these public var preoperties,
    //  so you can change the values at run-time
    private let guageColor: UIColor = .systemBlue
    private let guageLineWidth: CGFloat = 16.0
    private let labelFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)

    // this will be set in commonInit()
    private var labelInset: CGFloat = 0

    // array to manage the labels
    private var theLabels: [UILabel] = []
    
    private let guageLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        guageLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        guageLayer.strokeColor = guageColor.cgColor
        guageLayer.lineCap = .round
        guageLayer.lineWidth = guageLineWidth
        
        layer.addSublayer(guageLayer)
        
        // we'll use this to determine how much to inset the elements
        //  so they don't extend outside the view bounds
        let sizingLabel = UILabel()
        sizingLabel.font = labelFont
        sizingLabel.text = "000"
        sizingLabel.sizeToFit()
        labelInset = sizingLabel.frame.width * 0.5
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // so the labels will fit inside the view bounds
        let labelRect: CGRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: labelInset, dy: labelInset)
        
        // arc needs to be smaller than the bounds,
        //  and small enough so the labels are on the outside
        let arcRect: CGRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: labelInset * 2.0 + guageLineWidth * 0.5, dy: labelInset * 2.0 + guageLineWidth * 0.5)
        
        // center point
        var cntr: CGPoint = .init(x: arcRect.midX, y: arcRect.midY)
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()

        // clockwise arc leaving a 25% (90º) "gap" at the bottom
        //  start at 135º (90.0º + 45.0º)
        var startAngle: Double = 135.0
        //  end at 3/4 of a full circle
        var endAngle: Double = startAngle + 270.0

        bez.addArc(withCenter: cntr, radius: arcRect.width * 0.5, startAngle: startAngle.degreesToRadians, endAngle: endAngle.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)

        // shift it down, so its centered vertically
        bez.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: (arcRect.height - bez.bounds.height) * 0.5))
        // set the guage path
        guageLayer.path = bez.cgPath
        
        // we shifted the arc down, so we need to shift
        //  the center point down so the labels also shift down
        cntr.y += (arcRect.height - bez.bounds.height) * 0.5
        
        // radius for the label positioning circle
        let labelRadius: CGFloat = labelRect.width * 0.5
        
        // we want the first (Zero) and last (100) labels to be a bit higher
        //  than the bottom arc ends
        // so let's add 10º to the start angle
        //  and subtract 10º from the end angle
        let angleOffset: Double = 10.0
        startAngle += angleOffset
        endAngle -= angleOffset
        
        // get the total range of degrees
        let angleRange: Double = endAngle - startAngle
        
        // position the labels on the "outside" circle,
        //  based on their values as a percentage of the max number of degrees
        for (value, label) in zip(values, theLabels) {
            let pct: Double = Double(value) / 100.0
            let thisAngle: Double = startAngle + (angleRange * pct)
            let pt: CGPoint = CGPoint.pointOnCircle(center: cntr, radius: labelRadius, angle: thisAngle.degreesToRadians)
            label.center = pt
        }
        
    }
    
}

class BasicGuage: UIView {

    private let guageLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        guageLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        guageLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        guageLayer.lineCap = .round
        guageLayer.lineWidth = 16.0

        layer.addSublayer(guageLayer)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // radius is 1/2 of the width
        let radius: CGFloat = bounds.width * 0.5
        
        // center point
        let cntr: CGPoint = .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        
        // clockwise arc leaving a 25% (90º) "gap" at the bottom
        //  start at 135º (90.0º + 45.0º)
        let startAngle: Double = 135.0
        //  end at 3/4 of a full circle
        let endAngle: Double = startAngle + 270.0
        
        bez.addArc(withCenter: cntr, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle.degreesToRadians, endAngle: endAngle.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
        
        // set the guage path
        guageLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    }
    
}

class BasicGuageWithLabel: UIView {
    
    private let guageLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    private let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        guageLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        guageLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        guageLayer.lineCap = .round
        guageLayer.lineWidth = 16.0
        
        layer.addSublayer(guageLayer)
        
        // add the label
        label.text = "Test"
        addSubview(label)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // radius is 1/2 of the width
        let radius: CGFloat = bounds.width * 0.5
        
        // center point
        let cntr: CGPoint = .init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        
        // clockwise arc leaving a 25% (90º) "gap" at the bottom
        //  start at 135º (90.0º + 45.0º)
        let startAngle: Double = 135.0
        //  end at 3/4 of a full circle
        let endAngle: Double = startAngle + 270.0
        
        bez.addArc(withCenter: cntr, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle.degreesToRadians, endAngle: endAngle.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
        
        // set the guage path
        guageLayer.path = bez.cgPath
        
        // position the label
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.center = cntr
    }
    
}

class zzzGuage: UIView {
    
    private var guageLineWidth: CGFloat = 16.0
    
    private let labelFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)
    private var labelInset: CGFloat = 0

    // this allows us to use the "base" layer as a shape layer
    //  instead of adding a sublayer
    lazy var guageLayer: CAShapeLayer = self.layer as! CAShapeLayer
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        
        guageLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        guageLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        guageLayer.lineCap = .round
        guageLayer.lineWidth = guageLineWidth
        
        // we'll use this to determine how much to inset the elements
        //  so they don't extend outside the view bounds
        let sizingLabel = UILabel()
        sizingLabel.font = labelFont
        sizingLabel.text = "000"
        sizingLabel.sizeToFit()
        labelInset = sizingLabel.frame.width * 0.5
        
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // arc needs to be smaller than the bounds,
        //  and small enough so the labels are on the outside
        let arcRect: CGRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: labelInset * 2.0 + guageLineWidth * 0.5, dy: labelInset * 2.0 + guageLineWidth * 0.5)

        // center point
        var cntr: CGPoint = .init(x: arcRect.midX, y: arcRect.midY)
        
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        // clockwise arc leaving a 25% "gap" at the bottom
        bez.addArc(withCenter: cntr, radius: arcRect.width * 0.5, startAngle: .pi * 0.75, endAngle: .pi * 0.25, clockwise: true)
        // set the guage path
        guageLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    }
    
}


class BasicGuageTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    //let guage = BasicGuage()
    let guage = BasicGuageWithLabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(guage)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            guage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            guage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guage.widthAnchor),
            guage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            guage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])

        guage.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
}
```

and an example view controller class:

```
class GuageTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let guage = Guage()
    
    var testValues: [[Int]] = [
        [0, 10, 50, 90, 100],
        [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
        [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 100],
        [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
        [0, 15, 30, 50, 70, 85, 100],
    ]
    
    let infoLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .light)
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(guage)
        
        infoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(infoLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            guage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            guage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guage.widthAnchor),
            guage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            guage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guage.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        guage.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        nextTestValues()
    }
    
    func nextTestValues() {

        var s: String = "\n"
        testValues.forEach { vals in
            if vals == testValues.first {
                s += "   --> "
            } else {
                s += "       "
            }
            s += "\(vals)\n"
        }
        infoLabel.text = s

        let theseValues = testValues.removeFirst()
        testValues.append(theseValues)
        guage.values = theseValues
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        nextTestValues()
    }
    
}
```

Tapping anywhere cycles through some sample value sets:

[image]

[image]

[image]

and so on.

Note: This is ***Sample Code Only*** ... and all examples assume a square (`1:1` ratio) view.